# Find value in column, if present AND has different last digit, return text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

[image: Spreadsheet scenario]

I have to check If the material number is the correct variant. To do so, I have to compare it to the New Version list. If in the New Version the 10 digit match and the last digit is "2", BUT in C2 the last digit is "1", I need it to return "Incorrect Variant".
The New Variant list shows only the few material numbers that shifted to "2", so not all of them are there and some might be the same as the material in column C, I only need to underlying which material is wrong because of the final "1".

Working formula:

=IF(COUNTIF(F:F,C2+1)>0,"Incorrect Variant","")

Comment: You posted 3 previous questions that are related. did any the responses to those questions help? We are not a free function writing service. Please show us what you have tried and we might be able to point out errors with your functions.

Comment: I tried all the formulas in the responses but none worked for me

Comment: Then please go back to those questions and explain what the problem is with the offered solutions. Note that many answers are not ready to use and require you to understand what is being done and adapt it for your own use

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that new variants increment by 1 and that you keep your New Version clean, then this works:

Cell D2 formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(F:F,C2+1)>0,"Incorrect Variant","")
```

Just change your reference (F:F) to wherever you keep your New Version column.

[image]

Comment: This works! thank you!! Can I ask you why did you put >0?

Comment: IF formulas work like this: IF(logical_test, [value if true], [value if false]). So, in this case, the logical test is this: Count the number of times a new version matches the Material column when adding a 1 to it and consider as TRUE when it EXCEEDS ZERO. 

Should this answer your question, please consider marking as an approved answer.